# Last kernel update to 16.04 don't mount my NAS by startup.

Tags: kernel, mount, fstab

After the kernel update 16.04 it seems like the fstab file has not been readend. At least my NAS is is not mounted, but the NAS do mount, when I use the mount commend in the terminal as administrator - using "sudo mount ...".

Is it a bug in the kernel? or do I have to change anything?

Comment: Try to look at the the output from `dmesg`and the logs from boot time in `/var/log`.

Comment: If you edit your question and include the line from fstab that would help a lot.

Comment: This are the lines from my fstab that work until yesterdays update:

Comment: Here the are:192.168.0.40:/volume1/Hjem /home/gert/Station1 nfs defaults 0 0
192.168.0.40:/volume1/photo /home/gert/DSFoto nfs defaults 0 0